# Custom Aggregate In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, aggregate

I have an app in Laravel connected to SQL Server in ubuntu.
This is my problem table with these fields:

**BranchID, SupplierID, StuffID, RegDate, SupplyCount, SoldCount** 

There is dynamic grouping query on BranchID, SupplierID, StuffID and RegDate.

I want to calculate summation of SupplyCount and SoldCount with BranchID grouping.
But here is the point:
I need sum(SupplyCount) at latest RegDate. So how can I implement this query as simple as possible:

```
Select
  BranchID, 
  SUM(SoldCount), 
  Sum(SupplyCount * (CASE MAX(RegDate) = RegDate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) )
FROM STUFFS
GROUP BY BranchID
```

But this isn't working, because aggregate func can't be called inside another agg func. I want to implement this as simple as possible.
I appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the easiest way to use subquery:

```
Select
  BranchID, 
  SUM(SoldCount), 
  (SELECT SUM(p.SupplyCount) FROM STUFFS AS p WHERE p.RegDate = MAX(s.RegDate) AND p.BranchID = s.BranchID)
FROM STUFFS AS s
GROUP BY BranchID
```

Comment: Missed the `AND p.BranchID = s.BranchID` ?

Comment: @Xalil I forgot about BranchId, Eric pointed to this mistake, I corrected my answer

Comment: @Xalil Backs updated the answer, remember to mark the answer if it helps ;)

Comment: @Backs Thank you, this query is generated dynamically.Meaning Grouping can be based on BranchID, SupplierID, StuffID, RegDate. One by one or in mixed mode. I supposed to accept your answer, But the sub-query should own a condition for grouping field. Do you think there's a way to implement this without sub-query? If there is not, I have to accept your answer.

Comment: @Xalil well, I don't know a better way, another variant - pre-select all MAX(RegDate) for each BranchID, but there is still group and join by `p.BranchID = s.BranchID`. So it will be the same